# Conditional split based on array variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, comparison

I need something like a T-SQL IN statement to filter records in a conditional split based on an array variable (or something similar)

I need to have a list of items that a column can be filtered on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Filip has indicated, there is no IN operator in the expression language. I did come up with some options though as I thought this sounded like an interesting problem.

My long analysis is on my blog: [Filter list in SSIS](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/filter-list-in-ssis.html)

### Conditional split

If you can transform your list of values into a delimited string, then you can use `FINDSTRING` and the current value to determine whether it's in the list. This provided the best throughput for my testing scenario.  `(FINDSTRING(@[User::MyListStr], [MyColumn],1)) > 0`

### Script task

I had assumed using a List in a script task to determine membership would provide the best performance but I was wrong. `Row.IsInList = MyListObj.Contains(Row.MyColumn);`

### Lookup/Cache Connection Manager

The third approach I had come up with was dumping the list into a Cached Connection Manager and then using that in a lookup task. I thought this was the easiest to conceptualize and maintain but the performance was lacking.

## Conclusion

For this problem domain, the FINDSTRING approach was the most efficient, by a considerable margin. The other three approaches consistently averaged a throughput of within 7 rows per millisecond of each other. I did find it interesting that the standard deviation of the FINDSTRING approach fluctuated so much. While this box is older and slower, there was not a considerable amount of activity going on during the package executions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no IN operator in [SSIS expression operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137538.aspx). And there is no similar operator. Since there is no such operator, You can't do that with built-in expressions and built-in Conditional Split. But You can do one of the following:

- use Script Transformation to check if particular column has that is in variable array, and add additional column (flag) with value 1 if it contains, 0 if not; then use Conditional Split on this flag added in Script Transformation, or
- it's better to put variables in database table and then use Lookup or Merge Join to check if row exists